# Is this true about Zubair (a companion)

Tags: practical-islam, sahaba

Is it true that prophet Muhammad’s close companion beat his wives? If so, how was he promised paradise?

Prophet Muhammad said:

> *Abu Bakr will be in Paradise, ‘Umar will be in Paradise, ‘Usmaan will be in Paradise, ‘Ali will be in Paradise, Talhah will be in Paradise,
> al-Zubayr will be in Paradise, ‘Abd al-Rahmaan ibn ‘Awf will be in
> Paradise, Sa’d will be in Paradise, Sa’eed will be in Paradise, and
> Abu ‘Ubaydah ibn al-Jarraah will be in Paradise.” (Narrated by
> al-Tirmidhi: 3680)*

But I’ve also read that he did this to his wives

> *Asma also recalled: “Whenever he reprimanded one of us, he would break off a branch from the wooden clothes hangers and beat her with
> it until he broke it over her.”
>
> Al-Zubayr’s wives complained that he had “some harshness towards
> women”.[41] Asma wanted a divorce after he tied her and her (unnamed)
> co-wife together by their hair and beat both of them “severely”.

https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2013/01/06/ten-sahabah-promised-jannah/
https://military.wikia.org/wiki/Zubayr_ibn_al-Awam#cite_note-44

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum wa rahmat Allahu wa barakatuh!

First of all, Just because some companions did beat their wives doesn't mean that they no longer deserve jannah, Or that beating wives is okay! We admit that beating wives is a major sin and oppression, But perhaps Asmaa forgave him? Especially that she made a poem about his death! Or He was right? And al zubayr did so many amazing things to islam, That he deserved to get forgiveness from Allah if this is true, Because what he had done to islam is too huge compared to his harshness towards his wife, And that's something that someone like him only gain out of his great service to islam.

First of all yes he is one of the amazing 10 companions who were promised Jannah.

Well about the first hadith:

*Asma also recalled: “Whenever he reprimanded one of us, he would break off a branch from the wooden clothes hangers and beat her with it until he broke it over her.”*

A sheikh called Abdullah ibn fahd Alkulify said that :

*> it's not authentic*

Even though i do not know if this sheikh is trustworthy in the science of hadith, I'm just copy pasting!

And about the second :

> *Al-Zubayr’s wives complained that he had “some harshness towards women”.[41] Asma wanted a divorce after he tied her and her (unnamed)
> co-wife together by their hair and beat both of them “severely”.*

Islamweb says  :

> *This narration was mentioned by Ibn al-Arabi, may God have mercy on him, in Ahkam al-Qur’an, and by al-Qurtubi in his interpretation and
> remembrance, on the authority of Ibn Wahb, on the authority of Malik,
> like this, and Judge Abu Bakr said: Strange.  Ibn Katheer mentioned it
> at the end and conveyed the strange ruling of Judge Ibn al-Arabi
> against him, and he did not trace it back or mention anyone else who
> spoke about it.  We did not find this narration narrated through
> another path, nor did those who attributed it to Malik mention who
> Malik took it from, may God have mercy on him. It is known that he did
> not recognize the names of the names, may God be pleased with them,
> and whoever thinks that this action did not come from him, may God be
> pleased with him, is the same person in piety and piety.  If it is
> true that some of this is attributed to the disciples of the Prophet,
> may God’s prayers and peace be upon him, Al-Zubair ibn Al-Awwam, may
> God be pleased with him, then this is not part of the thanked
> striving, rather it is part of the forgiven striving - God willing -
> in which one cannot imitate him, for the best guidance is the guidance
> of Muhammad, may God’s prayers and peace be upon him.  And peace be
> upon him.*

[Source](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/189849/%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%89-%D8%B5%D8%AD%D8%A9-%D8%A3%D8%AB%D8%B1-%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%88%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%A7)

And that she asked him for divorce and his son defended her from al zubayr then : In the book of seyar aalam al nubalaa by al zahabi he said that it's mawdoo, And considered another similar narration of this situation as weak : [Source](https://shamela.ws/book/22669/1628)

And from al dorar hadith site i found :

Al-Zubair hit Asma bint Abi Bakr, and she screamed so that Abdullah ibn Al-Zubair, so he approached, and when he saw him, he said, “Your mother is divorced if you come in.” Abdullah said to him, “Will you make my mother under the control of your talaq?” So he lunged at him, And he freed her, and she left him. He said, “And I was a boy.” Perhaps I took the hair on Zubair’s shoulders.
Narrator: Urwa bin Al-Zubayr |  Muhaddith: Al-Haythami |
Source: Mujmaa Al-Zawaid
Page or number: 4/341
Summary of the hadith’s ruling: It contains Abdullah bin Muhammad bin Yahya bin Urwa, and he is weak |
Clarification of the hadith’s ruling: Its chain of transmission is weak

[Source](https://dorar.net/hadith/search?q=%D9%81%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AA%20%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%20%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B1%20%D9%81%D8%A3%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%84%20%D9%81%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%87%20%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%83%20%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%20%D8%A5%D9%86%20%D8%AF%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%AA&st=w&xclude=&rawi%5B%5D=)

And another ruling of the similar narration on dorar site :

Al-Zubayr divorced asmaa;  So he took a urwa, and he was young at that time.

Narrator: Urwa |  Muhaddith: Shuaib Al-Arnaout |  Source: Verification of seyar aalaam al nubalaa

Page or number: 2/292 |

Summary of the hadith’s ruling: Its narrators are trustworthy, but it is interrupted.  |
Clarification of the hadith’s ruling: Its chain of transmission is not valid

[Source](https://dorar.net/hadith/search?q=%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B1%20%D8%B7%D9%84%D9%82%20%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1&st=w&xclude=&rawi%5B%5D=)

And in an authentic hadith al zubayr said to asmaa : [Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5224#:%7E:text=By%20Allah%2C%20your%20carrying%20the%20date%20stones%20(and%20you%20being%20seen%20by%20the%20Prophet%20(%EF%B7%BA)%20in%20such%20a%20state)%20is%20more%20shameful%20to%20me%20than%20your%20riding%20with%20him.%22)

Note the translation of hadith says : "more shameful" but it should be "more painful"

shows how al zubayr felt pain that he saw his wife in pain and don't forget that asmaa made a poem for him when he got murdered!  :

غدرَ ابن جرموزٍ بفارسِ بهمةٍ

يومَ الهياجِ وكان غيرَ معرِّدِ

يا عمرو لو نبَّهتهُ لوجدتَهُ

لا طائشاً رعشَ الجنانِ ولا اليِدِ

ثكِلَتكَ أمّكَ إن قتَلتَ لمسلِماً

حلَّت عليكَ عقوبةُ المُتَعَمّدِ

From : [Source](https://diwandb.com/poem/%D8%BA%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2-%D8%A8%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D9%87%D9%85%D8%A9.html)

the "it's narrators are trustworthy" doesn't mean that the hadith is weak or authentic, according to Albany

Note : I'm just a copy paster, not a Muhaddith, i recommend you to ask a sheikh of hadith about these :), i just gave sources that may help, you're welcome!